# What blueprints become available during story?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

As I progress, I realize that some blueprints open up throughout the story and don't have to be researched. Are these random or are they always the same and is there a list over those? Seems you can easily waste research point if you don't know that.

Comment: There's a difference between research and development in the game. Research is just making the development of something available. Often developing something ahead of the automatically unlocked research what you want to go for because by the time it becomes "common" in the game world (i.e. you can just develop the item), it's obsolete, or at least the bare minimum to have any fighting chance, so - what you're asking isn't really so much a defined list - your answer is: level first,  always based on missions, level, and relationships.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blueprints, which are automatically unlocked are never even shown on the research screen. You simply unlock all the common research projects whenever you reach the required level+1. I.e. once you reach Lvl 21, you get access to all common level 4 blueprints.

Additionally you also get access to new nomad blueprints at those intervals. Those cannot be bought or researched either.

List of automatically unlocked research projects:

> Possibly incomplete, feel free to add, if I missed something.

- M-8 Avenger Assault rifle
- M-96 Mattock Assault rifle
- Incisor Sniper rifle
- Viper Sniper rifle
- M-23 Katana Shotgun
- Disciple Shotgun
- M-3 Predator Pistol
- Carnifex Pistol
- M-5 Phalanx Pistol
- Biotic amplifier melee weapon
- omni blade melee weapon
- Pathfinder Armor set
- Intitaitve Armor Set
- Maverick armor set
- all nomad blueprints

Comment: I can't speak for the asker, but I interpret the question as asking for a list of what these common research projects are. In other words, a full answer should have the names of guns and armor in it.

Comment: from what I can see he is mostly concerned about wasting research points on projects, which he gets automatically. But that can't happen as you cannot spent research points on automatically unlocked projects. I'll add a list to my answer, though it may be incomplete.

Comment: Not at my Xbox to confirm, but I think you're probably missing the Charger and Viper.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, these are the tiers where the various automatic upgrades are unlocked (as well as where things like Mods level up in vendors inventories):

Tier I: Level 1
Tier II: Level 6
Tier III: Level 11
Tier IV: Level 21
Tier V: Level 31
Tier VI: Level 41
Tier VII: Level 51
Tier VIII: Level 61
Tier IX: Level 71
Tier X: Level 81

There are no further tiers.

Comment: Yeah, but for which weapons do you automatically get access to those tiers?

Comment: The tier rules don't apply to some of the Remnant gear. I have a Tier X chest plate and not even half way to level 81. I also have a level VII legs and not level 50.